# Consuming Web Services With Python

Tags: python, rest

I am running into issues with the code I am using for this project. The idea behind the project is to program a REST web service of my choice using Python. However, my IDLE is claiming I cannot import the Requests module. I have tried to use Json as well, but that doesn't seem to work either mainly because both claim not to have a Get function. I have not ever used either of these modules before so I am somewhat lost on what to do. Here is the project in question and my code as well as the error messages it generates"

**Project Instructions**

> Write a client to consume a REST web service of you choice using Python. There are many listings of such services but an excellent resource is ProgrammableWeb (https://www.programmableweb.com/). Your information should produce useful information. I.e. a dump of cryptic data is not the desired product. Examples could be a weather forecast, stock quote, Bible verse, etc.,

> Your solution should present the user with a question with the answer contributing to the data used in the REST web service call. For example, a weather forecast would prompt the user to enter a zip code or other location information. Once the web transaction is complete, the program should prompt again with the same question to complete another transaction. This should continue until the user enters a specified termination condition.

> You output must be presented in an understandable manner. Dumps of XML, JSON, etc., are substandard and will be graded accordingly.

> Hint:
> Another site with a simple REST API can be found here: http://labs.bible.org/api_web_service Be sure to click on the examples and look at the address bar of your browser. That is what you will need to generate with the Python requests module.

> You are free to use any REST web service you find but I recommend this one if you are looking for something straightforward. One word of caution, some services require you to request access via an API key. The approval may not be immediate so you will want to find something sooner rather than later. The example I listed above requires no approval.

**Code**

```
import json

URLWeb = "http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage="

print("Listen! To terminate the program, type 'exit'.")
while True:
    print("-" * 30)
    putIn = input("Heyo! To get some random facts, type 'random': ")
    print("-" * 30)
    if putIn.lower()== "random":
        response = json.get(URLWeb + "random")
        properText = "-->".join(response.text[3:].split('</b>'))
        print(properText)
    elif "exit" == putIn.lower():
        print("Ending program.")
        break
    else:
        print("Hey, dude! Use proper input!"
```

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

Any explanation or assisting by tomorrow night would be appreciated. I've been trying to figure out my Python projects, but, honestly, the teacher hasn't exactly been a big help.

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire code? Especially there are no imports shown for json or requests. If you're importing the [standard python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) there is indeed no `get` function.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy that in. That's my bad. There is Import Json there, I just forgot to get it. I'll add that in. It was a mere oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install the `requests` package with `pip` in the command line (Windows) or Terminal (MacOS/Linux).

```
pip install requests
```

Then you can use the `get` function from the `requests` package:

```
response = requests.get(URLWeb + "random")
```

Comment: Does this apply to an IDLE as well? I'm using Pycharm for this.

Comment: IDLE has nothing to do with python executing an import statement.  But if you have more than one python on your system, you have to install the packages for the same python that you run IDLE with.  There are numerous question answers explaining the details.

Comment: You can actually use the ‘terminal’ in PyCharm for the ‘pip install requests’ command. That will download and install the package.

Comment: Thank you! This worked nicely! Too bad I had to ask a stranger online because the teacher said nothing about how to do this in our readings. He's been giving us projects covering topics we hadn't even so much as touched in our readings so you can maybe imagine my frustration there.

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes, that is quite an essential piece of information he left out then ;-)